# Problema ao criar "Zend_Session"

Tags: php, zend, session

Estou tentando criar uma sessão no `Zend` da seguinte forma:

```php
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {

  Zend_Session::start();

  $session = new Zend_Session_Namespace(); 

  $login = explode('-', $_POST['login']);

  $codigo = $login[1];

  $banco = $admin->fetchAll('SELECT banco FROM tbl_clientes WHERE codigo = ' . $codigo);

  Zend_Registry::set('banco', $banco[0]['banco']); 

  $session->banco = $banco[0]['banco'];
}
```

Porém ao tentar acessar a variável `$session->banco` em outra página ela simplesmente não existe!

**OBS.**
Logo que eu atribuo o valor dela, ela recebe o valor de `$banco[0]['banco']`.
Normalmente, eu preciso deste valor para poder setar o `defaultAdapter` do `Zend_Db_Table` e disponibilizar ele na aplicação para que eu possa acessar o banco.
Este banco vai estar em um registro na consulta que eu estou fazendo acima.

Eu estava tentando tratar tudo isso no `Bootstrap.php` mas vi que não da muito certo, de qualque forma estou com dificuldades para salvar essa informação, o banco me retorna o seguinte erro:

```
'No adapter found for models_DbTable_TblChamado'
```

<sup>Se houver uma forma melhor de fazer isso, estou aberto a sugestões.</sup>

Comment: Na outra página você executou o `Zend_Session::start();` novamente antes de acessar o `$session->banco`?

Comment: Recomendo vc dar uma olhada no ZF2. Ficou mt legal, principalmente os esquemas de ServiceManager e EventManager. São ferramentas mt poderosas, ainda mais se usadas junto com o novo sistema de modules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolvi da seguinte forma, no `Bootstrap.php` fiz toda a configuração, primeiro eu verifico se existe o login, consulto os dados no banco, salvo os valores para acessar o banco do usuário específico e salvo na sessão:

```php
        Zend_Session::start();

        $bd = $this->getPluginResource('db');
        $params = $bd->getOptions();

        $admin = new Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql($params['params']);

        $bd = Zend_Db::factory('Pdo_Mysql', $params['params']);
        Zend_Registry::set('Db_admin', $bd);
        $sessionDb = new Zend_Session_Namespace('banco');

        /**
         * Inicia a base de dados do aplicativo com o usuario. 
         */
        if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
            $login = explode('-', $_POST['login']);
            $codigo = $login[1];
            $banco = $admin->fetchAll('SELECT banco FROM tbl_clientes WHERE codigo = ' . $codigo);
            Zend_Registry::set('banco', $banco[0]['banco']); 
            $sessionDb->banco = Zend_Registry::get('banco');
        }

        $nomebanco = $sessionDb->banco;

        //se existe os dados de login eu pego os dados do banco do 
            //cliente e registro pra que fique disponível em toda a app
            if ($nomebanco) {
                $pdoParams = array(
                    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
                    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => true,
                    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true,
                    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES UTF8');

                $database = array(
                    'host' => 'localhost',
                    'username' => 'root',
                    'password' => '',
                    'dbname' => $sessionDb->banco,
                    'driver_options' => $pdoParams
                );
                $db = Zend_Db::factory('Pdo_Mysql', $database);
                Zend_Db_Table::setDefaultAdapter($db);
                Zend_Registry::set('Zend_Db', $db);

            }
```